# How can I grab the attachment url with social-feed.js?

Tags: javascript, instagram

I'm using [social-feed.js](https://github.com/pavelk2/social-feed) to pull in an image through Instagram into a template.

Right now, the only way to do this is using:

`{{=it.attachment}}`

Which outputs the image element. To anyone who is familiar with this library, is there an undocumented way to capture the src url only?

eg. `{{=it.attachment_src}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this, the way I got around it was to add a new line at 533.

`post.attachment_src = element.images.standard_resolution.url;`

If you want to achieve the same with the other social networks, you would need to add this line to those parts in the code too.